# Tableview cell row height with storyboard in code

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What is the equivalent of this property in code ?

This is the custom row height for a TableViewCell
I want to set it programmatically from inside the cell .

Please note : I know how to do it from tableview delegate , table view row height , auto layout etc… so that’s not my question .

I want to specifically edit this property in code instead of storyboard .

[image]

Comment: Use this -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614852-rowheight

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you don't want to use those two methods if it's not too personal?

Answer (score 1):

You answered your question yourself. You can use `tableView.rowHeight = 20` in `viewDidLoad()` or the delegate function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return 20
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the height of a cell and make it dynamic according to the contents of the cell, use `heightForRowAt` as below:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension // you can set this value static 
}
```

Make sure this will work perfectly only when all the constraints of your cell are attached properly.

Comment: Do not use the `heightForRowAt` delegate method if you return the same value for all rows. In this case, simply set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension` in `viewDidLoad`. It's much more efficient this way.